# Flutter: setting an initial state from constructor

Tags: flutter, widget, state, stateful

I am trying to set the initial value of a boolean from a value passed into my widget. My attempt right now looks like:

```
const CustomLikeButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.liked,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool liked;

  @override
  State<CustomLikeButton> createState() => _CustomLikeButtonState();
}

class _CustomLikeButtonState extends State<CustomLikeButton> {
  bool _liked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    bool _liked = widget.liked;
    super.initState();
  }
```

but it is giving the error:

```
Non-nullable instance field '_liked' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.
```

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

its null safety
you define `bool _liked;` but without any value.

you can try

```
late bool _liked;
```

or

```
bool _liked = false; // or true
```

or

```
bool? _liked;
```

then set the value you get from the constructor

```
 _liked = widget.liked
```